# Delete a child attribute from json file

Tags: java, json, qjsonobject

I have the following HTTP JSON-response in Java, which represents a user object.

```
{
    "account": "Kpatrick",
    "firstname": "Patrick",
    [
    ],
    "instances":
    [
        {
            "id": "packerer-pool",
            "key": "packerer-pool123",
            "userAccount": "kpatrick",
            "firstname": "Patrick",
            "lastname": "Schmidt",

        }
    ],
    "projects":
    [
        {
            "id": "packerer-projectPool",
            "projectKey": "projectPool-Pool",
            "cqprojectName": "xxxxx",
        },
       {
            "id": "packerer-secondproject",
            "projectKey": "projectPool-Pool2",
            "cqprojectName": "xxxx",

        },
        {
            "id": "packerer-thirdproject",
            "projectKey": "projectPool-Pool3",
            "cqprojectName": "xxxx",
        }
    ],

    "clients":
    [
    ],
    "dbid": 76864576,
    "version": 1,
    "id": "dbpack21"
}
```

Now, I want to search a specific project with the help of the `projectkey` (for example "projectPool-Pool2"). After that, I want to delete the element completely. Because my target is to send a HTTP post-call without this project.

The result should be similar to below for my HTTP post-call:

```
    {
    "account": "Kpatrick",
    "firstname": "Patrick",
    [
    ],
    "instances":
    [
        {
            "id": "packerer-pool",
            "key": "packerer-pool123",
            "userAccount": "kpatrick",
            "firstname": "Patrick",
            "lastname": "Schmidt",

        }
    ],
    "projects":
    [
        {
            "id": "packerer-projectPool",
            "projectKey": "projectPool-Pool",
            "cqprojectName": "xxxxx",
        },
        {
            "id": "packerer-thirdproject",
            "projectKey": "projectPool-Pool3",
            "cqprojectName": "xxxx",
        }
    ],

    "clients":
    [
    ],
    "dbid": 76864576,
    "version": 1,
    "id": "dbpack21"
}
```

First i have parsed the response to a string.

```
    private static String getContent(HttpResponse response) {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity == null) return null;
    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();
        return line;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And now i am trying to search the specific project, but i don't know how to continue.

```
String StringResponse = getContent(JsonResponse);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(StringResponse);
JSONArray ProjectsArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray("projects");
```

Is that approach correct?

Best Regards!

Comment: StringResponse and ProjectArray in the final code segment should be lower case, as they are objects not classes.

Comment: Thanks for your fast replay. And how else can i handle it?

Comment: The lower case variables is just a small convention issue. Check out my answer to the question

Comment: Is this a valid JSON , can you parse it . I get multiple errors. If you can post a valid JSON , its easier to test

Comment: i have corrected two commas and a clip on. Does it work now?
It should be okay now! It's the response of my HttpGet - methode.

That's the Problem, i want to parse it, but i can't or i want to delete a specific project :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your array, try something like...

```
// Array to store the indexes of the JSONArray to remove
ArrayList<Integer> indexesToRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// Iterate through projects array, check the object at each position
// if it contains the string you want, add its index to the removal list
for (int i = 0; i < projectsArray.length; i++) {
    JSONObject current = projectsArray.get(i);
    if (current.get("projectKey") == "**DESIRED PROJECT KEY**") {
        indexesToRemove.add(i);
    } 
}
```

Now you can iterate through your indexes to remove, and remove the corresponding object from the array with the JSONArrays remove method (not sure what it is called, the code above is from memory). Make sure to remove your items BACKWARDS, otherwise you will delete earlier items, which will change the indexes, resulting in your removing an incorrect item if you then remove another index.

```
// Going through the list backwards so we can remove the highest item each 
//time without affecting the lower items
for (int i = indexesToRemove.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    projectsArray.remove(indexesToRemove.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay! 
I got the error: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["projects"] not found.

Is that a object or attribute? Because "projects" have even own attributes. I don't understand that exactly :-/

Comment: Sorry I meant to respond to your second question but I kept getting sidetracked. For the future when you are working with JSON, its good to use a JSON viewer if you are finding it difficult to read the raw format, that can make it much easier to see why your add/retrieve operations aren't working. Glad you sorted it anyway!