# How do i get, modify and post a json object?

Tags: java, json, http-post, http-get

as mentioned in my older topic 3 days ago - [Last Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296779/delete-a-child-attribute-from-json-file/39296937#39296937)

i got a json response and changed it to a string. The Json Response represents an User-Object. Within the User-Object i wanted to search for a specific project and delete it. After that, i want to post it again via HttpPost.

```
    private static String getContent(HttpResponse response) {
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity == null) return null;
BufferedReader reader;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    reader.close();
    return line;
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

}

```
String StringResponse = getContent(JsonResponse);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(StringResponse);
JSONArray ProjectsArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray("projects");
```

Searching for a specific project by saving the attributes in a JsonArray.

```
ArrayList<Integer> indexesToRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < projectsArray.length; i++) {
JSONObject current = projectsArray.get(i);
if (current.get("projectKey") == "**ProjectName**") {
indexesToRemove.add(i);
}
}
```

Deleting the project...

```
for (int i = indexesToRemove.size()-1; i>=0; i--) 
{ 
projectsArray.remove(indexesToRemove.get(i));
}
```

That works perfect and my searched project is deleted. But the problem is, that i want to post the modified UserObject/String again via HttpPost. And my deleted project is just in my JsonArray "projectsArray" and not in my string from the beginning. I can't post "projectsArray"....

```
        HttpPost UserChange = new HttpPost (TestUserURL+user);  //TODO: 
        UserChange.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        UserChange.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        params = new StringEntity("ModifiedJsonString", HTTP.UTF_8);   // How do i get the complete Json string?
        UserChange.setEntity(params);

        HttpResponse UserChangeResponse = httpclient.execute(UserChange);

        HttpEntity entity2 = UserChangeResponse.getEntity();
            if (entity2 != null) {
                entity2.consumeContent();                       
            }
```

I need the "ModifiedJsonString", which includes the complete json file from the beginning.

```
params = new StringEntity(ModifiedJsonString, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code removes one of the selected project.

```
String jsonString = "{    \"account\": \"Kpatrick\",    \"firstname\": \"Patrick\",    \"instances\": [        {            \"id\": \"packerer-pool\",            \"key\": \"packerer-pool123\",            \"userAccount\": \"kpatrick\",            \"firstname\": \"Patrick\",            \"lastname\": \"Schmidt\"        }    ],    \"projects\": [        {            \"id\": \"packerer-projectPool\",            \"projectKey\": \"projectPool-Pool\",            \"cqprojectName\": \"xxxxx\"        },        {            \"id\": \"packerer-secondproject\",            \"projectKey\": \"projectPool-Pool2\",            \"cqprojectName\": \"xxxx\"        },        {            \"id\": \"packerer-thirdproject\",            \"projectKey\": \"projectPool-Pool3\",            \"cqprojectName\": \"xxxx\"        }    ],    \"clients\": [],    \"dbid\": 76864576,    \"version\": 1,    \"id\": \"dbpack21\"}";
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonString);

ArrayList<String> listOfNodes = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray projectArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("projects");
int len = projectArray.size();
if (projectArray != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        String projectId = ((JSONObject) projectArray.get(i)).get("projectKey").toString();
        if (!projectId.equals("projectPool-Pool2")) {
            listOfNodes.add(projectArray.get(i).toString());

        }

    }
}
// Remove the element from arraylist
// Recreate JSON Array
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray();
jsArray.addAll(listOfNodes);
jsonObject.remove(projectArray);
jsonObject.put("projects", listOfNodes);

System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
```

This for example , prints the following JSON string removing one of the projects.[image: Linted JSON]
Once you have this , you can then use this to create a StringEntity and then use it in HTTPPost calls. Hope it helps

Comment: Great! Thanks for your reply. The Resolution was this point: 

jsonObject.put("projects", listOfNodes);